# Using React how to append to a string every time a checkbox is checked and display in another input text field

Tags: reactjs, typescript, string, react-native, react-hooks

I want to update a text input field every time a checkbox is checked(true). Can someone please advise how can this be done please?.

I'm trying to click a checkbox and update another input field. Every time the checkbox is checked I want to add the date to a string.

Currently, my string value is being overwritten by the new value. I want it to be a string and not an array.

```
const [checkboxCheckedTrue, setCheckboxStatus] = useState(false);
 const [updateMyMsg, setmyMsg] = React.useState("");

  useEffect((): void => {
    if (checkboxCheckedTrue) {
      var a = new Date();
      const myMsg = "My Date is" + a;
      
      setmyMsg(myMsg );
    }
  });
```

My expected string should look like the following:

```
"Thu Sep 15 2022 15:52:41 <br/> Thu Sep 15 2022 15:52:41 <br/> Thu Sep 15 2022 15:52:41"
```

Comment: What is `checkboxCheckedTrue`? You just want to append a date string to the `updateMyMsg` string?

Comment: I'm trying to get the value of my checkbox using "checkboxCheckedTrue". Just updated the description.

Comment: I would not use an effect for that but simply an event listener `onChange`. Effects are better suited for synchronizing external state or similar situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to append a value to the `updateMyMsg` state any time the `checkboxCheckedTrue` value updates and is toggled true, use a functional state update to append to the previous state's value.

Example:

```
const [checkboxCheckedTrue, setCheckboxStatus] = useState<Boolean>(false);
const [myMsg, setMyMsg] = useState<string>("");

useEffect((): void => {
  if (checkboxCheckedTrue) {
    setMyMsg(myMsg => myMsg + (new Date()).toString() + "<br/>");
  }
}, [checkboxCheckedTrue]);
```

It might be simpler to use an array for the `myMsg` state and call `.join` when you want to use the state value.

Example:

```
const [checkboxCheckedTrue, setCheckboxStatus] = useState<Boolean>(false);
const [myMsg, setMyMsg] = useState<string[]>([]);

useEffect((): void => {
  if (checkboxCheckedTrue) {
    setMyMsg(myMsg => myMsg.concat((new Date()).toString()));
  }
}, [checkboxCheckedTrue]);
```

...

```
myMsg.join("<br/>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this please , hope it helps :)

```
const [updateMyMsg, setmyMsg] = React.useState("");

  useEffect((): void => {
    if (checkboxCheckedTrue) {
      var a = new Date().toDateString();
      const myMsg = `${updateMyMsg}${a}`;
      
      setmyMsg(myMsg );
    }
  },[checkboxCheckedTrue]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the message logs value while you have checked and un-check the checkbox but the value is true.

You need to manage the array of messages for every time while you need to checked the checkbox.

Something like this

**Example:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isCheckboxSelected, setCheckbox] = useState(false);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isCheckboxSelected) {
      const newMessage = new Date().toString();

      setMessages((messages) => [...messages, ...[newMessage]]);
    }
  }, [isCheckboxSelected]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value={isCheckboxSelected}
        onChange={() => setCheckbox((preValue) => !preValue)}
      />
      {messages?.map((message, index) => {
        return (
          <Fragment key={index}>
            <p>{message}</p>
          </Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```